# Sync iOS devices through app over network in Adobe AIR

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, adobe

I would like to take my programming skills to the next level and see if this project is possible with adobe AIR.

I would like to create an app that a teacher can use to administer an exam.  The students would be on their own iOS device.  The teacher would be able to start the exam from his/her device, and the students will see it start on their device.  Also, any information that the students take, like scores and names, would get sent back to get stored on the parent device.  Is this possible to code for adobe AIR if all synced devices are on the same network?

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction and let me know what I have to learn or read up on.  I don't know where to start.

Thank you!!
Josh

Answer (score 0):

I think of a few ways to do it:

1. using bluetooth to connect the devices

   - pros:

     - it will work with almost no delay
     - requires only client-side knowledge
   - cons:

     - it will work in close range
     - it's harder to setup - the 'host' should always create active sessions and connection is somehow unstable
2. using socket server

   - pros:

     - reliable
     - fast
     - stable as there is always active session and everyone can connect/disconnect from it
   - cons:

     - harder to create (requires backend knowledge)
     - requires specific server that supports sockets
3. using http requests

   - pros:

     - easy to implement
     - stable
   - cons:

     - huge traffic
     - requires backend knowledge

In all cases you will need some kind of users level management - which is the host (teacher) and who is a student.
There might be other ways, but these are the most common used. Unfortunately, I must say it's not that easy task to do and I will suggest you to find some backend guy and enjoy the project together.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed descriptions!  Ill see if i can find a partner!

Comment: How many bluetooth devices can be connected at once?  Is 20 too many?